What does the values of Joint Probabilities indicate here?
I am going through MIT OpenCourseWare for learning probability and I found this question in the assignments, however I am a little confused on what does these Joint Probability values indicate.
My understanding is that the AUC of the joint pdf till x=1 is 1/2 and from 1<x<2 is 3/2, which I think is wrong as the slope of the line is still |1/2|and AUC is 1/2 which makes sense as AUC_left and AUC_right should sum to 1.
So what is this 3/2 here?


That picture is showing you the joint PDF.   The density is $\frac 12$ for points in the left hand triangle and $\frac 32$ for the right hand triangle.  Note that each right triangle has geometric area $\frac 12$ so the weighted area is $\frac 14$ for the left hand one  and $\frac 34$ for the right hand one, and those sum to $1$ as they should.

Thank you for the explanation, it is much clearer now.

It simply means
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}, & 0 \le y \le x \le 1 \\
\frac{3}{2}, & 1 < x \le x+y \le 2 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$
It's not actually clear what the density is at $X = 1$, but I've revised my answer to make a choice, so as to remove ambiguity in the definition.

Thank you for the explanation, could you please explain the limits corresponding to 3/2. I understand that for x, limits will be, 1<x<=2 and for y the limits will remain 0<=y<=1. So how, did you end up on the limits?

@AamirAhmadAnsari The region with density $3/2$ is bounded by a triangle with vertices $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$, and $(2,0)$; the edges of this triangle are contained in the lines $y = 0$, $x = 1$, and $x+y = 2$.  The interior of the triangle must satisfy the simultaneous inequalities $y \ge 0$, $x \ge 1$, and $x + y \le 2$.  Adding $x$ to both sides of the first inequality gives $x + y \ge x$.  Then we combine them into a single statement:  $$1 \le x \le x + y \le 2.$$

This makes sense, thank you so much.
